# solving this recurrence equation

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

is it possibel to solve the equation

g$(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(x/n) $ for $ f(x)$ with other methods different from taking the Mellin transform on both sides ?? thanks.

Comment: could you tell us more about $f$?

Comment: f(x) is of the order $ f(x)= O(x^{a}) $ at least for big 'x' and an integer positive 'a'